# For Ubuntu phone, how should "device offline" and "device not found" errors be addressed when reflashing?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, flash, phone

I am attempting to reflash an Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu phone. When I do this, I get various errors, resulting in the device entering a boot loop. What might be going wrong? How might Ubuntu be flashed on the device correctly? The device appears to enter fastboot successfully.

```
>wget http://people.canonical.com/~jhm/barajas/recovery-krillin.img

>ubuntu-device-flash touch --channel ubuntu-touch/stable/bq-aquaris.en --bootstrap --recovery-image recovery-krillin.img
2016/09/27 17:34:09 Expecting the device to be in the bootloader... waiting
2016/09/27 17:34:11 Device is |krillin|
2016/09/27 17:34:11 Flashing version 35 from ubuntu-touch/stable/bq-aquaris.en channel and server https://system-image.ubuntu.com to device krillin
13.08 MB / 69.37 MB [========>____________________________________________] 18.85 % 743.22 KB/s 1m17s2016/09/27 17:34:30 Start pushing /home/user/.cache/ubuntuimages/gpg/image-signing.tar.xz to device
2016/09/27 17:34:30 Start pushing /home/user/.cache/ubuntuimages/gpg/image-master.tar.xz to device
2016/09/27 17:34:30 Start pushing /home/user/.cache/ubuntuimages/ubuntu-touch/stable/bq-aquaris.en/krillin/version-35.tar.xz to device
15.55 MB / 66.97 MB [===========>__________________________________________] 23.21 % 874.06 KB/s 1m0s2016/09/27 17:34:30 Done pushing /home/user/.cache/ubuntuimages/gpg/image-master.tar.xz to device
2016/09/27 17:34:30 Done pushing /home/user/.cache/ubuntuimages/gpg/image-signing.tar.xz to device
2016/09/27 17:34:30 Done pushing /home/user/.cache/ubuntuimages/ubuntu-touch/stable/bq-aquaris.en/krillin/version-35.tar.xz to device
66.97 MB / 66.97 MB [=========================================================] 100.00 % 966.22 KB/s 
2016/09/27 17:35:22 Start pushing /home/user/.cache/ubuntuimages/pool/custom-7ee762289981fe54f1cd374a17c6aabaf2720fb8d5b5a5b2e56e860032b3eb16.tar.xz to device
2016/09/27 17:35:22 error pushing: error: device not found

>ubuntu-device-flash touch --channel ubuntu-touch/stable/bq-aquaris.en --bootstrap --recovery-image recovery-krillin.img
2016/09/27 17:35:57 Expecting the device to be in the bootloader... waiting
2016/09/27 17:35:57 Device is |krillin|
2016/09/27 17:35:57 Flashing version 35 from ubuntu-touch/stable/bq-aquaris.en channel and server https://system-image.ubuntu.com to device krillin
12.38 MB / 298.13 MB [=>____________________________________________________] 4.15 % 695.58 KB/s 7m0s2016/09/27 17:36:16 Start pushing /home/user/.cache/ubuntuimages/gpg/image-signing.tar.xz to device
2016/09/27 17:36:16 Start pushing /home/user/.cache/ubuntuimages/gpg/image-master.tar.xz to device
2016/09/27 17:36:16 Start pushing /home/user/.cache/ubuntuimages/ubuntu-touch/stable/bq-aquaris.en/krillin/version-35.tar.xz to device
12.55 MB / 298.13 MB [=>___________________________________________________] 4.21 % 697.56 KB/s 6m58s2016/09/27 17:36:16 Done pushing /home/user/.cache/ubuntuimages/gpg/image-master.tar.xz to device
2016/09/27 17:36:16 Done pushing /home/user/.cache/ubuntuimages/gpg/image-signing.tar.xz to device
2016/09/27 17:36:16 Done pushing /home/user/.cache/ubuntuimages/ubuntu-touch/stable/bq-aquaris.en/krillin/version-35.tar.xz to device
66.97 MB / 66.97 MB [===========================================================] 100.00 % 1.06 MB/s 
2016/09/27 17:37:01 Start pushing /home/user/.cache/ubuntuimages/pool/custom-7ee762289981fe54f1cd374a17c6aabaf2720fb8d5b5a5b2e56e860032b3eb16.tar.xz to device
2016/09/27 17:37:01 error pushing: error: device offline
```

Answer (score 0):

Instructions for installing Ubuntu on phones are here:

https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/

Comment: Hey there, I am familiar with these instructions and have followed them. The problem is that the installation does not appear to work when I follow the instructions. I have described the steps I have taken in the question.